# React tool tip not working when table is sorted

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, react-table

I have a react table, with a tool tip (on hover). When the page is loaded, tool tip is displayed on mouse hover,  But when i sort the table (any column)- the tool tip is not displayed. Any idea why ?
Sample code :

```
Header: label.action,
Cell: row => {
const booleanvalue = row.original.value;
return (
    <div>
    <ReactTooltip id='toolTip1'  effect='solid'>
    <span>tool tip label</span>
    </ReactTooltip>
    {booleanvalue &&
    <a data-tip data-for='toolTip1' href={link}>
    /a>
    }
```

Any thoughts ?